# Is it normal to use the gender-neutral word "child" instead of "son" or "daughter"?

Tags: word-choice

When talking about a specific, non-plural, child who is your son or daughter, is it normal to use "child" rather than "son" or "daughter"?

For example,

> I went with my child to the doctor's today.

I did a quick google for "With my child", and mainly came across cases involving hypothetical children who are not of a specified gender, for [example](http://www.stammering.org/first_time.html)

> How do I start a conversation with my child about stammering?

If it's currently not common to use "child" about a specific child, are people advocating such usage in order to not be discriminatory about gender?

Comment: (opinion) It's weirder than saying *my son* or *my daughter*, but it's less weird than saying *my sibling*.

Answer (score 3):

Only the most extremist political-correctness police would object to using *son* or *daughter* when speaking about a single child whose gender is known; the usual objection to using gender-specific language is when you're applying it to a generic-person-of-unknown-gender and making some sort of assumption. Most speakers talking about multiple children of the same gender would use *boys* or *girls*.

It is preferable to use a gender-neutral term (*child*) when talking about children generically, as in your second example, and the terms *children* or *kids* (much more casual) are generally used when referring to multiple, mixed-gender youngsters.

Comment: Sometimes a parent might use a more gender-neutral term (like _children_, or more likely, _kids_) when talking about more than one child. In other words, I might say, "I took my _daughter_ to the doctor's office," but I might say, "I took my _kids_ to the dentist." This is particularly true if the kids in tow are mixed gender; I somehow doubt I'd be likely to blurt out the more wordy, "I took my son and daughter to the dentist."

Comment: @J.R. Good point, and updated.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think *child* is a very common word to use in situations like this, but *kid* is quite common when the person you're speaking to doesn't know the gender of your child and the gender doesn't really matter. For example:

> Hey Joe, can you cover my shift for an hour tomorrow? I have to take my kid to the doctor.

You could just as easily say *son* or *daughter* there, but if the person you're speaking to isn't really acquainted with your child I think *kid* might even be more common than specifying the gender. *Child* would definitely sound odd, though.

Answer (score 2):

In the USA, 'child' is commonly used in this context, but sounds a bit formal. A more casual alternative is 'kid'.